# url construction in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, web-services, rest, networking, retrofit2

i am trying to learn Retrofit 2.0 and tried example at http://tutorialwing.com/android-retrofit-library/ 
but as i go through tutorial i found that it is saying,
 base url (https://api.stackexchange.com) + end url("/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow"") = final url ("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow".
) 
but how search is appended automatically although it is not present in end url.below is my code for making request to API.

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://api.stackoverflow.com";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor=new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**APIinterface.java**

```
@GET("/2.2/search/{order}/{sort}/{tagged}&site=stackoverflow")
    Call<ArrayList<Questions>>loadQuestions(@Query("order")String order, @Query("sort")String sort, @Query("tagged")String tag);
```

but i am not getting any result. after placing interceptor i was able to see url of request is : https://api.stackoverflow.com/2.2/search/%7Border%7D/%7Bsort%7D/%7Btagged%7D&site=stackoverflow?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android and after hitting this url it redirect me to this url :  https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android i am not able to find where i was made mistake. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`order`, `sort` and `tagged` are part of the `Path` of the url, so you need to use the `@Path` annotation for that. The only query is `site=stackoverflow`.

```
@GET("/2.2/search/{order}/{sort}/{tagged}&site=stackoverflow")
Call<ArrayList<Questions>>loadQuestions(@Path("order")String order, @Path("sort")String sort, @Path("tagged")String tag, @Query("site") siteName);
```

should yeld the url you want.

Edit: if you want to query `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow` then your definition should be

```
 @GET("/2.2/search")
 Call<ArrayList<Questions>>loadQuestions(@Query("order")String order, @Query("sort")String sort, @Query("tagged")String tag, @Query("site") siteName);
```

or alternatively you can use `@QueryMap` to provide a single argument

Comment: still it is redirecting to https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown?tagged=android&site=stackoverflow and by looking at url sort, order & tagged is not  also query  parameter ? as we have to specify value for that.

Comment: you have to decide if it query of path. They are two different things. You can't guess. Do you have the definition of the endpoint you are querying ?

Comment: @HardikMehta No, anything that follows `?` is query string. Check the [URI generic syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) for better understanding.

Comment: @Blackbelt it is open api  https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android&site=stackoverflow . i was wondering why it is appending http/1.1

Comment: @Blackbelt have you forget String site name? or it should be same as you write

Comment: just copy/paste what I wrote

Comment: @Blackbelt stil not working it is not fetching question